# Installing packages globally with npm is failing on Windows with rimraf error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I attempt to install packages globally on my Windows machine, it fails due to rimraf missing.   What's weird is this happened all of a sudden, it worked fine this morning and it's happening on Azure DevOps-hosted agents as well.

I tried updating npm, forcing a npm cache clean, restarting, and updating node to the latest lTS.  Nothing seems to work.  I don't see any open issues on cliui, so I'm thinking this is on our end somehow but I can't seem to find the solution.

```
PS C:\projects\456\some-site> npm install -g @angular/cli@15.2
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\123a\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\123a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\src\operators'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\123a\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\rxjs\\src\\operators'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'C:\\Users\\123a\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'C:\Users\123a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\observable'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'C:\\Users\\123a\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\rxjs\\internal\\observable'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\123a\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js install --force --cache=C:\Users\123a\AppData\Local\npm-cache --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! npm ERR! path C:\Users\123a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\git-cloneIxP6PW
npm ERR! npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c npm run compile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > cliui@8.0.1 precompile
npm ERR! npm ERR! > rimraf build
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm ERR! 'rimraf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
npm ERR! npm ERR! operable program or batch file.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\123a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-01T23_47_36_842Z-debug-0.log

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\123a\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-01T23_47_27_622Z-debug-0.log
```

**EDIT**

- Windows 11
- Run on both cmd line and PowerShell
- Node version: v18.16.0
- NPM Version: 9.6.5
- Command run to force npm cache clear: `npm cache clean --force`

Comment: Use NVM, and try a lower version of node, like 14 for example

Comment: Issues has been reported on GitHub angular cli repo: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/25110

Answer (score 0):

This situation resolved itself - I am guessing a release happened for one of the sub-dependencies that got later got fixed.

Comment: is it a faux paux to mark your question correct when you didn't really fix anything?